# Draw within the bounds of a div

Tags: three.js, glsl

I pass the pixel coordinates together with the size of the div as uniforms to the shader:

```
const targetElement = document.querySelector(".targetElement");
const targetElementW = targetElement.clientWidth;
const targetElementH = targetElement.clientHeight;
const targetElementX = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
const targetElementY = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;

material.uniforms = {
    uTargetCoords: { value: new THREE.Vector2(targetElementX, targetElementY) },
    uTargetSize: { value: new THREE.Vector2(targetElementW, targetElementH) },
};
```

To convert the pixel coordinates to screen coordinates I use this:

```
float x_ndc = 2.0f * (uTargetCoords.x + 0.5f) / uTargetSize.x - 1.0f;
float y_ndc = 2.0f * (uTargetCoords.y + 0.5f) / uTargetSize.y - 1.0f;
vec3 newposition = vec3(x_ndc, y_ndc, position.z);
gl_Position =  vec4( newposition, 1.0 );
```

I want to place a shader on top and within the bounds of a div.
Nothing is rendered to the screen.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Why is the clip space position calculated from uniforms? This always results in the same position. The position must be calculated from the attributes.

Comment: @Rabbid76 can you help with a small example please?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I tried to pass the values through the attributes like this:     material.attributes = {
      uTargetCoords: {value: new THREE.Vector2(x, y)},
      uTargetSize: {value: new THREE.Vector2(fullscreenW, fullscreenH)},
    };
Still no luck... Can you help?